# PHP MultiDimensional Array with ints

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

at the moment I pass one of my functions an array like so

```
$inputs = array("FOOD" => "Pancake");
```

And then in my function I do something like the following

```
foreach ($inputs as $label => $data)
{
    echo ($label . $data);
}
```

The above is only an example I have just written so I hope it is correct.  Anyways, the function which has that foreach loop also has the following within it

```
$this->SetFillColor(190,205,44);
```

Now for each loop, I also want to set the fill colour of the output.  So I was thinking about doing something like the following instead

```
$inputs = array("FOOD" => array("Pancake", '190,205,44'));
```

If I var_dump the array I am passing my function, I see

```
array:1 [▼
  "FOOD" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "PANCAKE"
    1 => "190,205,44"
  ]
]
```

So this all seems correct.  Now in my function I do

```
foreach($inputs as $label => $data){
    foreach($data as $content => $colour) {

        $this->SetFillColor($colour);

        $this->Cell(65, 7, $label, 0, 0, 'L', 1, 0);
        $this->Cell(100, 7, $content, 0, 0, 'L', 1, 0);
    }
}
```

Now I have a couple of problems.  Firstly, it seems to output two rows.  The first cell prints out FOOD like it should do but the second cell prints out 0 (should be PANCAKE).  The second row once again prints out FOOD, but the second cell prints out 1.

So how can I get it printing out just the first row?  The other problem is $colour, because this is a string when it needs to be an int I think.

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

foreach($inputs as $label => $data){
    $this->Cell(65, 7, $label, 0, 0, 'L', 1, 0);
    // content is on index 0 
    $this->Cell(100, 7, $data[0], 0, 0, 'L', 1, 0);
    // color on index 1 
    $this->SetFillColor($data[1]);
}
```

Or maybe even better create an object of \stdClass like this:

```
<?php

$foo[0]['food'] = new \stdClass;
$foo[0]['food']->content= 'Pancake';
$foo[0]['food']->color = '190,205,44';

$foo[1]['food'] = new \stdClass;
$foo[1]['food']->content= 'Apple';
$foo[1]['food']->color = '255,0,0';


for($i=0,$cnt=count($foo);$i<$cnt;$i++) {
    foreach($foo[$i] as $label => $data) {
      $this->Cell(65, 7, $label, 0, 0, 'L', 1, 0);
      $this->Cell(100, 7, $data->content, 0, 0, 'L', 1, 0);
      $this->SetFillColor($data->color);
    }
}
```

Edit:
You can do this too:

```
<?php
    $foo[0]['food']->color = new \stdClass;
    $foo[0]['food']->content= 'Pancake';
    $foo[0]['food']->color->r = 190;
    $foo[0]['food']->color->g = 205;
    $foo[0]['food']->color->b = 44;
```

... [snip]

```
    $c = $data->color;
    $this->SetFillColor($c->r,$c->g,$c->b);
```

Or even do it more OOP style

```
<?php

class color {

    private $r;
    private $g;
    private $b;

    public function get_r() {
        return (float) $this->r;
    }

    public function get_g() {
        return (float) $this->g;
    }

    public function get_b() {
        return (float) $this->b;
    }

    public function set_r($r) {
        $this->r = $r;
        return $this;
    }

    public function set_g($g) {
        $this->g = $g;
        return $this;       
    }

    public function set_b($b) {
        $this->b = $b;
        return $this;       
    }

    static public function factory() {
        return new color;
    }

    public function __construct() {
    }

}

class food {

    private $content;
    private $color;

    public function get_content() {
        return $this->content;
    }

    public function get_color() {
        return $this->color;
    }

    public function set_content($content) {
        $this->content = $content;
        return $this;
    }

    public function set_color(color $color) {
        $this->color = $color;
        return $this;
    }

    static public function factory() {
        return new food;
    }  

    public function __construct() {
    }   
}

$color = color::factory()->set_r(255)->set_g(0)->set_b(0);
$dataarray[] = food::factory()->set_content('Apple')->set_color($color);            

foreach($dataarray as $food) {
    echo $food->get_content();
    echo $food->get_color()->get_r();
    echo $food->get_color()->get_g();
    echo $food->get_color()->get_b();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly.  Is there any way to convert the colour string to 3 float values?

Answer (score 3):

I think you wanted to write

```
$inputs = array("FOOD" => array("Pancake" => '190,205,44'));
```

so that `'Pancake'` is a key that has a color string as its value.
Otherwise you should adjust your code to read like this:

```
foreach($inputs as $label => $data){
    $content = $data[0];
    $color = $data[1];

    $this->SetFillColor($colour);
    $this->Cell(65, 7, $label, 0, 0, 'L', 1, 0);
    $this->Cell(100, 7, $content, 0, 0, 'L', 1, 0);
}
```

Either way should do the trick.

---

Currently `$inputs = array("FOOD" => array("Pancake", '190,205,44'));` just sets the `'FOOD'` entry of `$inputs` to contain an array that has keys of `0,1` and so your `$content` variable will iterate `0,1` while `$color` iterates the values `'PANCAKE','190,205,44'`.